# Active Directory running user creation VBS outside of server doesnt grant groupmembership

Tags: windows, vbscript, server, active-directory

my problem is:
when i run my user creation script at my server, it works fine, a user gets created and has a membership (according to a .txt file)

when i run that same script outside of my server, the user gets created but doesnt have memberships

when i run that same script as admin outside of my server, the user gets created but doesnt have memberships

so this is the relevant code that adds memberships:

```
Dim fso, f, Row, Field
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile ("\\some\folder\user.txt",1,0)

Do while not f.AtEndOfLine
Row = f.readLine
Field = split(Row,",")
Username = Field(0)
Group = Field(1)
Lastname = Field(2)
Password = Field(3)
ScriptP = Field(4)
Project = Field(5)
Call UserCreation(Username,Group,Lastname,Password,ScriptP)
Loop

f.Close
Wscript.Quit(0)

Sub UserCreation (Username,Group,Lastname,Password,ScriptP)
Dim ouo, b
Set ouo = GetObject("LDAP://OU=abcOU,DC=my,DC=domain")
Set b = ouo.Create("user", "CN=" & Group & " " & Lastname)
Dim WshShell, ret
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
b.Put "sAMAccountName", Username
b.Put "userPrincipalName", Username & "@my.domain"
b.Put "scriptPath", ScriptP
b.SetInfo
b.SetPassword Password
b.AccountDisabled = False
b.SetInfo

cmdbegin = "cmd /C dsmod group"
CN = "CN=TN_" & Project & ",OU=projectOU,DC=my,DC=domain" 
oudc = "OU=abcOU,DC=my,DC=domain"
cmdmid = "-addmbr"
grpadd = cmdbegin & " " & AddQuotes(CN) & " " & cmdmid & " " & AddQuotes("CN=" & Group & " " & Lastname & "," & oudc) & " >>\\some\folder\log.txt"
WshShell.Run grpadd
```

that log.txt just adds a row like this at completion:

```
dsmod was successful:CN=TN_Test,OU=projectOU,DC=my,DC=domain
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `dsmod` instead of using VBScript's `GetObject()` to [add a user to a group](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_add_user_to_group.aspx)? Even in cases where it doesn't work, you'd probably get better error messages to troubleshoot.

Comment: this script was written by a former coworker, since he left we stuck with this script and adjusted it sometimes. It does work everytime reliably, but only if you start it from one of our domain controllers

Comment: That makes sense, since `dsmod` is only installed by default on a domain controller. (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc732406(v%3Dws.11))) Is `dsmod` even installed on the computer you're trying to run this from?

Comment: ahhh didnt know that command is server only, so if i replace that dsmod command i should be able to run the script outside of our dc?

Comment: If `dsmod` is not installed on that computer, then that's definitely the problem. So yes :)

Comment: How is the account being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is likely that `dsmod` is not installed on the computer you're running this from, since [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc732406(v%3Dws.11)) says that it is only installed by default on domain controllers. That can be confirmed by just running `dsmod` from the command line.

But that also seems like the hard way to do it. You can replace everything from the `cmdbegin` line to the end with this:

```
Set group = GetObject("LDAP://CN=TN_" & Project & ",OU=projectOU,DC=my,DC=domain")
group.Add(b.aDSPath)
```

The `group` variable will be a [`IADsGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsgroup) object, so you can use its [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsgroup-add) method to add the user.